# さくらサーバーの初期ドメインのリダイレクト

Tags: php

さくらサーバーの初期ドメイン
`https://○○○.sakura.ne.jp/●●●(変更できない指定フォルダ)` のURL(すでにSSL化済み)を使って
サイトを作りたいのですが
URLを `https://○○○.sakura.ne.jp` にリダイレクトしたいのです。
指定フォルダ直下にある.htaccessの一番下に

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abcd\.sakura\.ne\.jp(:80)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://○○○.sakura.ne.jp/$1 [R=301,L]
```

と書けばよいでしょうか？やってみたのですが、うまくいきません。

どなたかご教示いただけますと大変助かります。

Comment: さくらの解説ページがあるので　https://help.sakura.ad.jp/206054622/  見て下さい。

Comment: このページをみて色々やってはいるのですが、うまくいきません。

Comment: さくらはいくつかサービスを提供しているのですが、質問されている対象は[さくらの**レンタル**サーバ](https://help.sakura.ad.jp/206053142/)のことで良いでしょうか。そうすると、"`●●●(変更できない指定フォルダ)`"と書かれているのはウェブ公開ディレクトリ `www` ということになるかと思いますが、合っていますでしょうか。ここまでの前提が正しいなら、`.htaccess` に何も書かなくとも所望の動作になるかなと思うのですが、具体的にはどういう問題が発生しているでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。wwwという変更できないフォルダは共通なのですね。わかっていませんでした。その通りです。初期ドメインでWordpressのサイトを作るとサイトのアドレスがhttps://○○○.sakura.ne.jp/wwwとなってしまうのです。これをhttps://○○○.sakura.ne.jp/にしたいとさくらのサポートに問い合わせたのですが、サポート外で答えられないと言われ困っています。

Comment: wordpressならもしかして、管理画面　設定ー＞一般ページの　WordPress アドレス (URL)とサイトアドレス (URL)に、https://○○○.sakura.ne.jp/wwwと設定されていませんか？　サイトルートにwordpressをインストールした場合はhttps://○○○.sakura.ne.jpと設定されているはずです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ヒントをいただき調べてやっと解決しました。ずーっと悩み続けていたので本当に心から感謝しています。こんな簡単なことだったとは・・・解決に向けてお時間をいただき、本当にありがとうございました。http://kawatama.net/web/974　こちらを参考にしました。

Answer (score 1):

[さくらインターネットの.htaccessによるアクセス制御　：暗号化(SSL)を有効としている場合、暗号化しているページへ誘導したい](https://help.sakura.ad.jp/206054622/#06) より

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

でリダイレクトできます。

**追記、**
さくらの共有レンタルサーバの通常設定は、ドメインが　”アカウント名.sakura.ne.jp”の時、ウェブ公開ディレクトリ（ドキュメントルート）は、”/home/アカウント名/www/” に設定されていて　変えられない公開フォルダーとかないと思いますが（間違えていたらごめんなさい）
**参考までに、**
”/home/アカウント名/www/abc/”を ドキュメントルートとしてリダイレクトするには、（”アカウント名.sakura.ne.jp”でアクセスできる様に）
ドメインの振り分け記述を以下の様に書けばできると思います。（２０世紀末の共有サーバで使われていたような）

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(アカウント名.sakura.ne.jp)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abc/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%{HTTP_HOST}/abc/$1/ [L]
```

**注意！　無限LOOPさせない様に、気をつけて作業して下さい**

Comment: 書き込みありがとうございます。暗号化しているページへのリダイレクトはできています。ただ、さくらサーバーの初期ドメインはhttps://○○○.sakura.ne.jp/●●●(変更できない指定フォルダ)となっており、例えばフォルダ名がacbだとするとURLがhttps://○○○.sakura.ne.jp/abcになってしまうので、https://○○○.sakura.ne.jp/へリダイレクトしたいのです。ご存知でしたら、教えていただけると本当に助かります。

Comment: これ以上は さくらへ問い合わせた方が、良いと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。https://○○○.sakura.ne.jp/wwwという初期ドメインURLが表示されるのでhttps://○○○.sakura.ne.jp/にしたいという質問です。わかりにくく説明不足でお時間をとらせてしまい、本当に申し訳なく思います。ありがとうございます。